# Expectation value and median

Tags: statistics

Let X be a random variable such that $E(X)$ exists.

What is the value of $b$ such that $E(|X-b|)$ is minimum?

My answer-

For $X$ discrete it is intuitive to see that $b=$median of the distribution, because minimising $E(|X-b|)$ is sort of minimising the distance of $X$ from $b$.

Suppose $X$ attains each $\{x_i|i=1,2\dots n\}$ with probability $\frac{1}{n}$ then,

$$E(|X-b|)= \sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_i-b|.P(X=x_i)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_i-b|$$

which is minimum when $b$=median. Is this correct?

Also what about the continuous case?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You didn't prove anything.

Comment: I know. That is why I am asking the question. To know whether median is the correct answer and if yes then how.